# What is the best way to save/retrieve array in iOS PG

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

i have an array of results based on calculation of other arrays of texts entered by the user.
i want to save the array as user clicks on "save results" button.
So i want to know what is the best way to do this.....NSUserDefaults or Databsase, or PList or
and how to save the array by that way.

Actually i have to use NSUserDefaults for that according to my project need
Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

Look into Core Data. It's performant, typically uses less memory than other options, gives you persistence for free.

There are lots of references on line that can help you get started. Try this article by Ray Wenderlich as a start:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

A Google search can give you many more.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just write the array to file

using

```
[array writeToFile:myOutputFile atomically:YES];
```

Here is a reference link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCGEFF

you can also load them from file with

```
[array initWithContentsOfFile:myInputFile];
```

here is another reference link

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-CBHBDFEE

just make sure that the output file is located in a writable location for your application.

**Note**

Normally a good starting point on an object is to get a brief overview of the functions for that object so you know what that object can accomplish.

Hope this helps.